# How can I let this div expand and overflow it's container in IE8?

Tags: php, javascript, css, internet-explorer-8

I found a nice css3 dropdown script, but I can't abandon ie8 users because last I read the are still 10% of visits. 
So, I tried this:

```
<div id="containerdiv" style="height: 35px; overflow: visible;" > 
<a href="#"><img src="images/1.jpg"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="images/2.jpg"
onmouseenter="document.getElementById('navdd1').style.display = ''"></a>
<div id="navdd1" 
   style="
          display: none; 
          margin-left: 100px; 
          background-image:url('images/blank_dropdown.jpg');
          line-height: 35px;
          width: 100px;"
   onmouseleave="document.getElementById('navdd1').style.display = 'none'">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a><br>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a><br>
</div>
</div>
```

The mouseenter and mouseleave seem to do what I want, but the un-hidden div stretches the container instead of overflowing it. I'll use php to detect their browser and only present this when they are on IE < 9. Ironically, the overflow portion of this does what I want in FF, but of course the mouseleave does not. How do I make this work?

Comment: you are suppose to use position:absolute; i guess

Comment: @GCyrillus As simple as it was, if you'll post that as an answer, I'll accept it. `position:absolute; left:100px;
          top: 35px;
          /* margin-left: 100px; */`

Comment: oki then :), great it helped you

Comment: You must have another problem, overflow:visible works in IE7/8. It's in IE6 that it's broken. (yes i just tested your code above in IE6/7/8, and in 7/8/9/10 it works) http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/overflow.html Not saying overflow is better than position or float, just saying it does work, and you probably have a doctype problem or other too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set `#navdd1` in `position:absolute;`.

```
#navdd1 {
          display: none; 
          margin-left: 100px; 
          background-image:url('images/blank_dropdown.jpg');
          line-height: 35px;
          width: 100px;
          position:absolute;
}
```

and probably `#containerdiv` in `position:relative;` to easily give coordonates to `#navdd1`.

Comment: You're right, I forgot to mention in my other comment that I put position:relative on my container, so my drop-down was absolute to it.

Comment: Trying to get permission from client to abandon IE8 support. :)